# Присвоить числу минус, если оно положительное

Tags: javascript

В общем есть задачка небольшая, если число положительное, то сделать его отрицательным, остальные не трогать. Пишу такой код:

```
 function makeNegative(num) {
  if (num <= 0){
  return Math.abc(num)
  } else {
  return -Math.abc(num)
  }
}
```

но не пойму почему пишет TypeError: Math.abc is not a function

Comment: потому что `Math.abs`

Comment: Если задачка сделать из положительного отрицательное, то зачем делаешь из отрицательного положительное?

Comment: Действительно abs не правильно написал, спасибо!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function makeNegative(num) {
  return (num > 0)? -num : num;
}
```

или

```
function makeNegative(num) {
  return -Math.abs(num);
}
```

Comment: А мой метод действительно не совершенен, Ваш идеально сработал, Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

У вас правильный метод, только ошибка в названии функции, правильно так: `Math.abs();`

Comment: Оу точно... спасибо, я только учусь и неловкие ошибки такие... Буду внимательней в следующий раз )